# Problem installation Blender 2.80 on EasyNote TK Ubuntu LTR 18.04

Tags: software-installation, graphics, intel-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, blender

I have been working with Blender for quite some time. Now I would like to go from Blender 2.79 to Blender 2.80. However, this gives a problem with the installation of on my Ubuntu 18.04 Packerd-Bell EasyNote TK. Laptop;

Laptop: Packerd Bell - EasyNote-TK85
Memory: 3.5 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core ™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz × 4
Graphic: Intel® Ironlake Mobile
GNOME: 3.28.2
Bit: 64 bit
Hard drive: 487.3 GB

Blender 2.80 seems to install from the Ubuntu Software store, but do not start when switching on with the blender Icon that does appear. Nothing happens. Blender 2.80 does not appear in Synaptic. And with the help of PPS installation from Thomas Schiex this also doesn't work. Of course I always uninstall the previous version.
Strangely enough, Blender 2.80 installed flawlessly on my wife's Dell laptop;

Laptop: Dell Inspiron N5110
Memory 3.8GiB
Processor: Intel® Core ™ i3-3210M CPU@2.10GHz x 4
Graphic: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
GNOME: 3.28.2
Bit: 64
Hard disk 491.2 GB

I have installed Ubunt 18.04 agains to make sure it is a clean installation. "Software updates" indicates that no additional drivers are required. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong with the PackardBell Easynote? Then I would like to hear it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Blender 2.8 does not support the Intel Core i3 CPU M380 Ironlake Mobile. Installation is therefore not possible. So I started working on a different laptop.